# How can I divide a string and assign a variable for each one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

I am building an image editor. To make presets, I have assigned each button a custom `data` value. Each button, when clicked, sets its internal values as the values of all range sliders in the document.

I solved this by first assigning each `filter-container` an onclick function that slashes the string and builds a new function. I assign this function to an existing button.
Finally, I click this button.

```
function setPreset(inp) {
    const key = inp.getAttribute("data-preset-key");
    document.getElementById("newbut").setAttribute("onclick", "useKey('" + key.replaceAll("-", "', '") + "')");
    document.getElementById("newbut").click()
}
```

The function assigned to the button is very long, and I would have to add a new variable every time I introduce a new input. This is why I come for your help. Can a function separate a string into unique values?

I hope I got my point across.

// edit, codepen snippet:

```js
//------------------------------- set preset
function keyReaderActivate() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".user-input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
      logVals();
    });
  }
  var setter = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-container");
  for (var i = 0; i < setter.length; i++) {
    setter[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      setPreset(this);
    });
  }
}

function setPreset(inp) {
  const key = inp.getAttribute("data-preset-key");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = key.replaceAll("-", ", ");
  document.getElementById("newbut").setAttribute("onclick", "useKey('" + key.replaceAll("-", "', '") + "')");
  document.getElementById("newbut").click()
}

function useKey(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".user-input");
  list[0].value = a;
  list[1].value = b;
  list[2].value = c;
  list[3].value = d;
  list[4].value = e;
  list[5].value = f;
}

function logVals() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".user-input");
  const arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const computers = list[i].value;
    arr.push(computers);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.join("-");
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around
}

nav * {
  border: solid;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="keyReaderActivate()">
  <div id="demo-intro"></div>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <nav>
    <div data-preset-key="20-14-70-62-100-50" id="1" class="filter-container">A</div>
    <div data-preset-key="10-50-11-50-100-30" id="2" class="filter-container">B</div>
    <div data-preset-key="80-100-11-62-50-50" id="3" class="filter-container">C</div>
    <div data-preset-key="50-50-100-62-100-70" id="4" class="filter-container">D</div>
  </nav>

  <div id="demo-name"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
  </ul>
  <button id="newbut">Check it</button>
</body>
```

```
function useKey(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(".user-input");
    list[0].value = a;
    list[1].value = b;
    list[2].value = c;
    list[3].value = d;
    list[4].value = e;
    list[5].value = f;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `split()` method do what you want?

Comment: It does initially, for getting the substrings. Then what? how do I assign one for each?

Comment: After you split into an array, you can assign to `list[i].value` in a loop.

Comment: `vals = this.dataset.presetKey.split("-"); vals.forEach((val, i) => list[i].value = val);`

Comment: How would that looked combined with this: 
`function setPreset(inp) {
 const key = inp.getAttribute("data-preset-key");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = key.split("-");
 ` do I add it here?`
} ` with it I mean this:`list[I]value; vals = this.dataset.presetKey.split("-"); vals.forEach((val, i) => list[i].value = val);`

Answer (score 0):

Split the data value using `.split('-')`, and then assign the values to each input.

And rather than assigning a new `onclick` attribute to the button every time you click on a preset, you can use a global variable to hold the selected preset, and refer to that in the click listener.

```js
let selectedPreset;

//------------------------------- set preset
function keyReaderActivate() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".user-input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("input", function() {
      logVals();
    });
  }
  var setter = document.querySelectorAll(".filter-container");
  for (var i = 0; i < setter.length; i++) {
    setter[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      setPreset(this);
    });
  }
  document.querySelector("#newbut").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (selectedPreset) {
      let keys = selectedContainer.dataset.presetKey.split('-');
      keys.forEach((key, i) => inputs[i].value = key);
    }
  });
}

function setPreset(inp) {
  const key = inp.getAttribute("data-preset-key");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = key.replaceAll("-", ", ");
  selectedPreset = inp;
  document.getElementById("newbut").click()
}

function logVals() {
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".user-input");
  const arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    const computers = list[i].value;
    arr.push(computers);
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr.join(", ");
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around
}

nav * {
  border: solid;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="keyReaderActivate()">
  <div id="demo-intro"></div>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <nav>
    <div data-preset-key="20-14-70-62-100-50" id="1" class="filter-container">A</div>
    <div data-preset-key="10-50-11-50-100-30" id="2" class="filter-container">B</div>
    <div data-preset-key="80-100-11-62-50-50" id="3" class="filter-container">C</div>
    <div data-preset-key="50-50-100-62-100-70" id="4" class="filter-container">D</div>
  </nav>

  <div id="demo-name"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input type="range" class="user-input"></li>
  </ul>
  <button id="newbut">Check it</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code is super complex and every time you will move a html range control you will have to refactor it.

My code is a shot prototype (far from perfect) which should give you an idear how this could be solved in a more generic way:

```js
const profiles = [
    { value1: 20, value2: 14, value3: 70, value4: 62, value5: 100, value6: 50 },
    { value1: 10, value2: 50, value3: 11, value4: 50, value5: 100, value6: 30 },
    { value1: 80, value2: 100, value3: 11, value4: 62, value5: 50, value6: 50 },
    { value1: 50, value2: 50, value3: 100, value4: 62, value5: 100, value6: 70 }
];

function loadProfile(number) {
  const rangeControls = document.querySelectorAll('.user-input');
  for (let i=0; i<rangeControls.length;i++) {
    rangeControls[i].value = profiles[number][rangeControls[i].id];
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav * {
  border: solid;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="demo-intro"></div>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <nav>
    <div id="1" class="filter-container" onclick="loadProfile(0)">A</div>
    <div id="2" class="filter-container" onclick="loadProfile(1)">B</div>
    <div id="3" class="filter-container" onclick="loadProfile(2)">C</div>
    <div id="4" class="filter-container" onclick="loadProfile(3)">D</div>
  </nav>

  <div id="demo-name"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><input id="value1" type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input id="value2" type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input id="value3" type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input id="value4" type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input id="value5" type="range" class="user-input"></li>
    <li><input id="value6" type="range" class="user-input"></li>
  </ul>
  <button id="newbut">Check it</button>
</body>
```